# How can I tell why Mathematica returns no solution to this system of nonlinear equations?

Tags: equation-solving, nonlinear

I'm trying to solve a system of 12 equations and 12 unknowns with the code below.

```
b = 5;
c = 0.2;
s = 0.3;
NSolve[
 {c == (b x2 - o y2)/(b x2),
  x5 == 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4,
  y5 == 1 - y1 - y2 - y3 - y4 - y6,
  x1 == 7 x2,
  x3 == x2,
  s == o y6 / (b x2 - o y2),
  s == (o y4 - b x4)/(b x2 - o y2),
  b x2 c (1 - s) == o y4 - b x4,
  b x2 c s == o y6,
  b (x1 + x4 + 2 x2 + 2 x5) == o (y1 + y4 + 2 y2 + 2 y5 + 3 y6),
  b (x1 + 2 x4 + x3) == o (y1 + 2 y4 + x3 + 2 y6),
  b (2 x3 + 4 x2 + 6 x5) == o (2 y3 + 4 y2 + 6 y5 + 6 y6)
  }, {o, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6}]
```

Mathematica happily tells me there are no solutions. I'd like to understand why. Are the systems of equations not independent? If so, can Mathematica tell me why?

**RESPONDING TO COMMENTS**

If I replace the variables at the top with fractions I still get no solutions.

```
b = 5;
c = 1/5;
s = 3/10;
Eqn = {c == (b x2 - o y2)/(b x2),
   x5 == 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4,
   y5 == 1 - y1 - y2 - y3 - y4 - y6,
   x1 == 7 x2,
   x3 == x2,
   s == o y6 / (b x2 - o y2),
   s == (o y4 - b x4)/(b x2 - o y2),
   b x2 c (1 - s) == o y4 - b x4,
   b x2 c s == o y6,
   b (x1 + x4 + 2 x2 + 2 x5) == o (y1 + y4 + 2 y2 + 2 y5 + 3 y6),
   b (x1 + 2 x4 + x3) == o (y1 + 2 y4 + x3 + 2 y6),
   b (2 x3 + 4 x2 + 6 x5) == o (2 y3 + 4 y2 + 6 y5 + 6 y6)
   };
V = {o, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6};
NSolve[Eqn, V]
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `0.2` with `1/5` and `0.3` with `3/10`?

Comment: If you throw `Eliminate` at your equations, it says that `s` has to be 1/2.

Comment: @J. M. I tried. Sadly, nothing changed.

Comment: @wxffles Can you show the arguments you placed in `Eliminate`? It's just returning `False` for me.

Comment: You need to clear your values for b, c and s.

Comment: `NSolve` gives an answer in version 10.2, but that answer is incorrect. Thanks to @Szabolcs for pointing this out. A bug report has been opened. To recover the old, correct behavior, one can use `Method -> "EndomorphismMatrix"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you attempt to `Reduce` your equations with respect to all unknown quantities, you obtain a result:

```
Clear[Evaluate[Context[] <> "*"]]
Reduce[{
   c == (b x2 - o y2)/(b x2),
   x5 == 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4,
   y5 == 1 - y1 - y2 - y3 - y4 - y6,
   x1 == 7 x2,
   x3 == x2,
   s == o y6/(b x2 - o y2),
   s == (o y4 - b x4)/(b x2 - o y2),
   b x2 c (1 - s) == o y4 - b x4,
   b x2 c s == o y6,
   b (x1 + x4 + 2 x2 + 2 x5) == o (y1 + y4 + 2 y2 + 2 y5 + 3 y6),
   b (x1 + 2 x4 + x3) == o (y1 + 2 y4 + x3 + 2 y6),
   b (2 x3 + 4 x2 + 6 x5) == o (2 y3 + 4 y2 + 6 y5 + 6 y6)},
  {c, b, o, s, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6}
] // ToRules
```

First solution set:

```
{c -> 4,
 s -> 1/2,
 x1 -> (7 (b - o))/(2 (6 b + o)),
 x2 -> x1/7, 
 x3 -> x1/7, 
 x5 -> 1/7 (7 - 9 x1 - 7 x4), 
 y1 -> -(x1/7), 
 y2 -> -((3 b x1)/(7 o)),
 y3 -> 1/14 (-3 x1 + 35 y2), 
 y4 -> 1/21 (21 x4 + 6 x1 x4 - 14 y2 - 84 x4 y2), 
 y5 -> 1/42 (42 + 15 x1 - 42 x4 - 12 x1 x4 - 91 y2 + 168 x4 y2), 
 y6 -> -((2 y2)/3)}
```

Second solution set:

```
{s -> 1/2,
 x1 -> (14 (b - o))/(-4 b + 7 b c + 4 o),
 x2 -> x1/7, 
 x3 -> x1/7, 
 x5 -> 1/7 (7 - 9 x1 - 7 x4), 
 y1 -> (-14 b + 14 o + 28 b x1 - b c x1)/(28 o), 
 y2 -> ((-1 + c) (x1 + 7 y1))/(14 (-4 + c)), 
 y3 -> 1/14 (-3 x1 + 35 y2), 
 y4 -> 1/84 (x1 + 84 x4 + 27 x1 x4 + 7 y1 + 21 x4 y1 - 56 y2 - 336 x4 y2), 
 y5 -> 1/84 (84 + 16 x1 - 84 x4 - 27 x1 x4 - 98 y1 - 21 x4 y1
                - 182 y2 + 336 x4 y2), 
 y6 -> 1/84 (x1 + 7 y1 - 56 y2)}
```

Two options are shown, and in both of them `s` has the value of $1/2$. This seems to be in conflict with the assumption you make above of $s=0.3$.

I would suspect, therefore, that the problem lies in the initial values you chose for the parameter `s`, and possible for `c` and `b` as well.

Comment: +1 In fact, `Solve[ ]` is more clear about the value for `s`